# missing binary operator before token "(" in Buildroot compilation

Tags: node.js, linux, compilation, buildroot

I'm trying to compile buildroot 2020.02 with xenomai 3.1 kernel and a linux kernel 3.18 but when i do :
make O=output , I got this error

```
**error**: missing binary operator before token "("
#elif __has_builtin(__c11_atomic_load) && \
```

The error came from host-nodejs 12.16.1 Configuring. I think there is a problem with the recognition of the macro __has_builtin .

The problem is located in the header file `putilimp.h`

Does anybody have an idea of how to fix it ?

I have gcc compiler version 8.X in my configuration

Here is the code of the paragraph that cause errors

```
#elif __has_builtin(__c11_atomic_load) && \
    __has_builtin(__c11_atomic_store) && \
    __has_builtin(__c11_atomic_fetch_add) && \
    __has_builtin(__c11_atomic_fetch_sub)
#    define U_HAVE_CLANG_ATOMICS 1
#else
#    define U_HAVE_CLANG_ATOMICS 0
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, experienced it with Buildroot 2020.02 and host-nodejs 12.16.1.

What I did was, I removed the package icu from Buildroot 2020.02 and copied the package icu from Buildroot 2019.02.8, into the package dir of Buildroot 2020.02.
Then edit the package/icu/icu.mk file, and change the version to 64-2.
After that, make a rebuild of Buildroot.

Comment: Hello , I tried your solution but it doesn't change anything . I got the same error

Comment: Interesting. Could you please fill in a bug report in our bug tracker at https://bugs.busybox.net/, which the exact Buildroot .config that allows to reproduce this issue, and the last ~200 lines of the build output ? This way we will able to investigate and fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @alex12345, Thanks you for you answer. Please which version of kernel linux did you use and which version of xenomai ?

Comment: I build the kernel(mainline kernel - 4.19) in different buildroot configuration. My other buildroot configuration is only for the root filesystem(where the node-js is).
Before I used Buildroot 2020.02, I used 2019.02.8 where I have manually added node-js 12.16.0 as an external package. There I had some problems building node-js with the ICU package, and managed to solve them by increasing the ICU version. So I just tried to use that same ICU here in Buildroot 2020.02 and it worked for me, but didn't go further to investigate the problem.